React Native POST Request Being Converted to GET Request
I'm on Android emulator sdk33. I'm trying to upload Images from my React Native app to my server which is equipped to handle image uploads. I'm using expo-image-picker to get the images from the user. When I send the post request with the body of the file array, I get an error saying:

[TypeError: Body not allowed for GET or HEAD requests]

This results in no calls to my server at all.
I have other GET and POST requests made to my server within this application so I know my API isn't the issue.
This is the function that my button "Upload Image" calls, it's supposed to do the post request and everything.
const uploadPhoto = async () => {
  try {
    await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    let files = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      quality: 1,
      allowsMultipleSelection: true,
    });

    if (!files.canceled) {
      const filelist = new FormData();
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        filelist.append("photos", files[i].assets[0].uri);
      }

      const res = await fetch(`${API}/ad/upload`, {
        headers: {
          method: "POST",
          "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
          Authorization: `Bearer: ${user.token}`,
        },
        body: { filelist },
      });

      console.log(res);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};


Its worth noting that the same thing happens with axios post too - I just get a simple "Network error" message instead.

method: 'POST' should be a property for fetch options instead of included in headers.

It might be because of your headers. Try moving your method out of headers like below:
const res = await fetch(`${API}/ad/upload`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`
    },
    body: filelist
});

Also, I think you need to pass filelist directly since it is form-data.

This makes sense - now I get the same error as I did using axios, which is Network request failed, even though I know the endpoint is good. Still no idea why. My endpoint isn't getting a request at all (i have console logs everywhere).

Try using Postman to check your endpoint is working as expected. Also, it might be because of emulator if you are using localhost which you need to update your api url accordingly.
